# htaccess rewrite with question mark full url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello guys I want to pass everything written in get.php? url = parameter (including question mark and special characters). I have get.php file the file content:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
print($url);
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^get/(.*)/?$ /get.php?url=$1 [L]
```

I can get up to the question mark when I do it this way.
Example: http://example.com/get/http://example.com?id=1&ad=mahmut

I am getting this result: http://example.com

How can i solve this problem? I tried many examples on the site but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trick is to not to use `RewriteRule` since you will get only URI part before `?`.

You should be using a `RewriteCond` with `THE_REQUEST` variable for this:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)url= [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+get/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ get.php?url=%1 [L,QSA]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`